# Django: print the last object of model for every (FK)

Tags: python, django

I have two models:

```
class Mantipo(models.Model):   
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...

class BillInitial(models.Model):
    tipo = models.ForeignKey(Mantipo, null=True, blank=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...
```

Let's say I have the following  objects of "BillInitial" model:

```
| id | tipo (FK) | nombre |

| 1 | uno | X | 

| 2 | dos | y | 

| 3 | cinco | x | 

| 4 | cinco | x |

| 5 | dos | z | 

| 6 | uno | X |
```

I want output the last objects of nombre (X) like:

```
| id | tipo (FK) | nombre |

| 4 | cinco | x | 

| 6 | uno | X |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
later_items_per_nombre = BillInitial.objects.filter(
    nombre=OuterRef('nombre'), 
    tipo=OuterRef('tipo'),
    pk__gt=OuterRef('pk')
)

BillInitial.objects.filter(nombre='x',).\
    annotate(is_not_last=Exists(later_items_per_nombre), ).\
    filter(is_not_last=False, )
```

Comment: this output only one object which is the last object

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the following:

```
BillInitial.objects.filter(nombre__iexact='x').order_by('-id')[:2]
```

May be `nombre__icontains` would be useful too.

Comment: my problem is with (FK) I need the last id of X for each "tipo" (FK)

Comment: May be `order_by('-tipo')` or `order_by('-tipo__id')`

Answer (score 0):

I think, if you use PostgreSQL you can build query with `distinct()` on tipo FK field. If not, maybe try with `last()` like:

```
small_x = BillInitial.objects.filter(
        nombre='x'
    ).last()
big_x = BillInitial.objects.filter(
        nombre='X'
    ).last()
```